# Firebase count child?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

how i can count child in FB DB

My code

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Chat");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
        long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        int chat = (int) count;
```

And my DB
[image]

I have to get 2 but get 4 and it doesn't change even when a new record is added. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `ChildEventListener`, which means that your `onChildAdded` gets called for each **child** node under `Chats`. So `onChildAdded` gets called once for `-M1j....t9B` and then again for `-M1j...3az`.

Then when you call `getChildrenCount()` you get the number of children under that specific chat message. So it seems like you have 4 properties for each chat message.

If you want to know the number of chat message, you'll typically want to use a `ValueEventListener`:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot. getChildrenCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to track when a new object is added in order to write +1 to the counter badge